# How can I delete my data at firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tableview and when I click delete It deleted from tableview But also I need to delete from firebase realtime database How can I do that ?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    NSString *uuid = self.firebaseUidArray[indexPath.row];
    [[[self.taskRef child:@"tasks"] child:uuid] removeValueWithCompletionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error, FIRDatabaseReference * _Nonnull ref) {
        [self.tasks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdateTableViewForDeleting" object:nil];
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the key of the items to remove, you can use write operation `setValue` and set it to `nil` it will be deleted

```
[[[self.taskRef child:@"tasks"] child:uuid] setValue:nil];
```